# Controll SVG with CSS IE/Edge

Tags: css, d3.js, svg

I am building a D3 map.  I have some text nodes in the map that represent place names.  Some of the labels I move slightly with CSS, for example

```
text#portTooltip-fos {
    dominant-baseline: hanging;
    text-anchor: end;
    transform:translatex(-1px);
}
```

This works fine in Chrome and Firefox but (surprise surprise) it doesn't work in IE11 or EDGE.  I don't need it to work in anything older than IE11 fortunately.

Does anybody know why this is and if there is a work around / polyfill?

Thanks

Comment: Does anything work on IE? Joking apart, your question have a simple answer: `dominant-baseline` is **not** supported on IE or Edge, have a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg558060(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @GerardoFurtado, ohh.  Thanks. If you put that as an answer, I can mark it

Comment: Thanks, but I just marked the question as a duplicate.